# Silverstripe 3 query with variable

Tags: silverstripe

I have used the following query in Silverstripe 2.x projects:

```
$obj = DataObject::get_one('Post', "\"URLSegment\" = '$segment'")
```

Does anyone know how I would replicate this query in the new ORM?
I have tried :

```
$obj = Post::get()->filter("\"URLSegment\" = '$segment'")
$obj = Post::get()->where("\"URLSegment\" = '$segment'")
```

And neither appear to work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're having is that DataObject::get() will return a collection of objects, whereas DataObject::get_one() will return a single object of the specified class. The Silverstripe 3 equivalent is:

```
$obj = Post::get()->where("\"URLSegment\" = '$segment'")->First();
```

With this scenario (as with SS2) you would need to make sure you're explicitly taking care escaping to avoid injection vulnerabilities. However the `filter` function will now take care of that for you. So what you really want now is:

```
$obj = Post::get()->filter('URLSegment', $segment)->First();
```

The related documentation is at: http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/topics/datamodel

Answer (score 0):

```
DataList::create('Post')->filter(array('URLSegment' => $segment))->First();
```

will also work.